# How to tune spring boot security configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I enabled spring boot security, and added some urls to exclusion list (porperty *security.ignored*) 
in application.yaml.

Now I want to add some new urls to exclusion list programmatically, in my configuration class.

How could i achieve this ?

PS I cannot edit yaml, I'm able to edit only configuration class.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to exclude some url patterns in java instead of yaml or properties.

Example:

If you need to exclude,

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
            .csrf();

}
```

If you need to ignore,

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/authFailure");
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: You seem didn't understand what i wrote :
I want to edit property security.config, that was defined in yaml. Again. I don't want to override it, just add to existing yaml

Comment: you said like can't edit yaml. you need to get this done in application.yaml ?

Comment: property is already defined in yaml. I just need alter in code. Don't override, just alter through adding values

Comment: specifically which value? Ideally Spring Security will be AutoConfigured. You need to Override HttpSecurity or WebSecurity if you need to exclude or ignore any URL pattern.

Comment: @Mebin Joe I got ya. I would mark this question as confusing since he says he can't edit yaml but wants it to be configured in yaml. And indeed ignoring urls programmatically you do with overriding method configure using web.ignoring.antmatchers.......

Comment: @Merv Yea. somewhat. voipp downvoted my answer. Can't identify what is his actual requirement.